# Why do I get an undefined reference to a symbol that is defined in the library I am linking?

Tags: c, linker, undefined-reference, nm, raylib

I was trying to compile an unrelated project when I got an undefined reference when using a specific function of the Raylib library.

I was able to reproduce this behaviour using the following test.c

```
#include <raylib.h>

int main(){
        InitWindow(500,500, "test");
        
        int w = GetRenderWidth(); // undefined reference symbol
                                                                                
        while(!WindowShouldClose()){                                            
                BeginDrawing();                                                 
                ClearBackground(BLACK);                                  
                EndDrawing();                                                   
        }                                                                       
        CloseWindow();                                                          
        return 0;                                                               
}
```

This code was compiled using the following command.

```
gcc test.c -o app -L/usr/local/lib -lraylib
```

The resulting output was

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxqgamX.o: in function `main':
code.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `GetRenderWidth'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Once I commented the offending line out however (`// int w = GetRenderWidth();`)
The app compiled fine and also was able run succesfully.

I examined the `libraylib.a` library in my `/usr/local/lib` folder using

```
nm /usr/local/lib/libraylib.a | grep GetRenderWidth
```

This resulted in the following outputt:

```
0000000000027b1e T GetRenderWidth
```

From this I surmise that the symbol is actually present in the library I linked and thus my question.
Why does my compiler (both `gcc` and `clang`) report an undefined reference on `GetRenderWidth()` but not on other symbols from the same library?

Comment: Do you have multiple installs of Raylib? Perhaps one that is searched and used before the one in `/usr/local/lib`? When building, if you remove the `-L/usr/local/lib` option, does it still find the Raylib library?

Comment: What does `width: height: title:` do? Are they an artifact of the code editor?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes it still displays the same behaviour including compiling and running when the GetRenderWidth function call is removed.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes sorry that is because I use neoclide with neovim so when I copied the text it copied everything neovim was displaying, I have removed it now.

Comment: "*Why does my compiler (both gcc and clang) report an undefined reference on `GetRenderWidth()` but not on other symbols from the same library?*" -- because the version of libraylib being linked does not provide an external definition of function `GetRenderWidth()`.  Since the one you are examining does define one, you must be linking a different library.  Possibly there's a shared-library version (`libraylib.so`) somewhere that is being linked in preference to the static one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is true there is also `libraylib.so` present in the same directory without the `GetRenderWidth` symbol. So that is probably it, but why would my compilers prefer that over the static one?

Comment: @AlaricdeRuiter It is up to your linker, not the compiler. Shared libraries are usually preferred over static ones, but there are options to change the behavior. On what OS/distribution are you?

Comment: @AlaricdeRuiter, it is a pretty common default behavior to prefer to link shared libraries instead of co-located static ones.  And this is the GNU linker's default, at least on most architectures.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah ok, was not aware of that thank you so much! Now I just wonder why that symbol was not present in the shared library but my current problem has been solved so I'll mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `/usr/local/lib` also contained a shared version of the same library which my compilers linked with. This version did not contain the `GetRenderWidth` symbol which is what caused my confusion. I was able to force my compiler to use the static library by replacing `-lraylib` with `-l:libraylib.a`.